# How to implement a Spinner in ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-spinner

How to setup **onItemSelected** for a spinner in ViewPager2.

I've set up the spinner in the ViewHolder() but can't figure out how to implement the **@Override onItemSelected**.

### ViewPager2

```
ViewPagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;

    ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }
```

### ViewHolder

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerViewViewHolder {
    private Spinner mSpinner;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        mSpinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(mContext, R.array.myArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResrouce(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       mSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
       mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)mContext);
```

### OnItemSelected ##

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Spinner Changed");
}
```

I would expect to see the "Spinner Changed" entry in the log after selecting a new spinner item.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference that it's in a `ViewPager2`. If it's being populated correctly, and not crashing from that cast, then `onItemSelected()` should be firing, provided the UI responds as expected. Are you sure you're not just missing the log print? Have you put a breakpoint there, just to check? Where is that `onItemSelected()` method, exactly?

Comment: are you trying to access spinner in recyclerview item?

Comment: why would you name a recycler adapter as `ViewPagerAdapter`?

Comment: I get the following error when trying to run the app, error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype. If I remove **@Override onItemSelected() ** the app runs fine. Log.d is ** onItemSelected**

Comment: @Sanjeev this is ViewPager adapter, I followed the guide on android Dev

Comment: `(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)mContext` – That's saying that `mContext` is the listener. Assuming `mContext` is the `Context` you passed to the `Adapter`, and also assuming that it's the `Activity`, then the `Activity` would need to implement `OnItemSelectedListener`, and that's where the `onItemSelected()` method would be.

Comment: @sanjeev `ViewPager2` is a `RecyclerView`, and takes a `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Comment: @MikeM. I don't know what to say.

Comment: @sanjeev Actually, I misspoke. It's a `ViewGroup`, but it uses a `RecyclerView` internally. Still takes a `RecyclerView.Adapter `, though.

Comment: @MikeM I've used a lot of your answers on other questions, I find it cool that you found your way to one of my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you say,

*I get the following error when trying to run the app, error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype.*

> Have you tried

```
mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Spinner Changed");
}
});
```

Comment: Cool, this solution works, what is the idea behind calling **new**. I'm trying to learn and would like to know why I used it as apposed to just copying and pasting.

Comment: `new OnItemSelectedListener()` is an interface that has the method `onItemSelected`. So if you want to initialise an interface or class you need to call `new` in java.